# DropDownListFor for a complex model having problems validating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, dropdownlistfor

I have other fields and dropdowns in an input form. They all validate fine. Even the two elements which do not properly validate front end still properly model bind in a post. I am not entirely sure why they are not validating. Here is the setup:

ViewModel

```
public class DataVM
{
 //Widgets used, populated from database
 public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; } 

 //Contains data to populate a dropdown with
 public GenericSelectList Containers { get; set; }

 //This will hold the relation between the widget and container
 //where widget is the local id, and container foreign id
 public List<NestedDictionary> WidgetContainers { get; set; }
}

public class NestedDictionary
{
    [RegularExpression("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/")]
    [Required]//This is not being enforced
    public int? ForeignId { get; set; }

    public int LocalId { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Widgets.Count; i++)
{
 @Html.Hidden("WidgetContainers["+i+"].LocalId", Model.Widgets.ElementAt(i).WidgetId)
 <div>
  <div>
   <span>Container Used</span><hr />
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.WidgetContainers.ElementAt(i).ForeignId,
    new SelectList(
     Model.Containers.Values,
     "Id",
     "DisplayFields",
     0
    ),
    " - Select A Container - "
   )
   <br />@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WidgetContainers.ElementAt(i).ForeignId)
  </div>
 </div>
}
```

Everything displays just fine. It is interactive and the values are correct. When posted, the correct data is passed into the correct places. However, if no Container is selected then the post is made just fine, with a value of `0` passed. Kind of at a loss here. Any ideas why the validation isn't working client side?

**EDIT**

Here is the rendered html of the hidden input, and the select element

hidden:

```
<input id="WidgetContainers_0__LocalId" type="hidden" value="39" name="WidgetContainers[0].LocalId">
```

select:

```
<select name="ForeignId" id="ForeignId" class="valid">
```

Clearly the select should have different attributes defined.

**Edit #2**

If I use

```
m => m.WidgetContainers[i].ForeignId,
```

then I get

```
<select id="WidgetContainers_0__ForeignId" name="WidgetContainers[0].ForeignId" class="valid">
```

Answer (score -1):

Because it's not null at all. If you want the Client side validation to work you should allow the `ForeignId` to be null not `0`
and that when you create the DropDown in the first place

```
new SelectList(
 Model.Containers.Values,
 "Id",
 "DisplayFields",
 0 // Don't set this default value
)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The zero was to show a default value was set. Regardless, when someone chooses a null option, the field should show as invalid. Instead of zero, it could be 1. If the user then selected the title option, which has a value of `""`, the validation should kick in. Note also the complete lack of data attributes on the select element.

Comment: I didn't know that you've some DropDown Itmes with null value then i expected that was the problem Sorry :)